# Module for creating "entity edit" form?

Tags: entities

Is there a module that will take an entity machine name and optionally id as input, and generate a suitable edit form as output?

Comment: Could you use [`entity_ui_get_form()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!entity.module/function/entity_ui_get_form/7) or are you specifically looking for an existing stable module?

Comment: It's my understanding that Entity API still expects me to implement the entire [entity_type]_form callback. That's the part I hope to automate.

Comment: @Letharion did you find anything ? I guess some parts of eck could be used for this, but they only edit fields, not properties. I am trying to find something that would do the form for properties, too :) Which of the two did you have in mind BTW ?

Comment: I've been meaning to check out http://drupal.org/project/entity_operations for this, but I'm not quite sure if it's going to helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create or edit a reference entity in a node add/edit form then you can use [Entity Connect](http://drupal.org/project/entityconnect) module.

If you want to have a separate page which `will take an entity machine name and optionally id as input` then you can have a look at the code in this module and build on that.

You may also take a look at [Inline entity Form](http://drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form)

Comment: Entity Connect looks nice (hadn't see that one before), but I think @Letharion is looking for something that can take the results from something like entity_get_info('my_custom_entity') and make the UI forms w/ actually having to build the forms manually with the Forms API.