# Best Practice to make edit-able programmatically custom made content

Tags: nodes

**SHORT VERSION**
Is there a Best Practice to make edit-able a programmatically custom made content in the same way the *My Account* node can be editated?

**LONG VERSION**
When i create new content through the admin tool *Add Content*, this content is automatically editable(given the right permissions)

An even better example of that (what i would like to actually replicate) is the *My Account* node.
The fields of this node are editable through Drupal generated form fields.

what i would like to know if there exist an hook or module that could allow me to "present" my content to Drupal so to have it add the same functionality to my custom content.

### EDIT 1

For learning purpose i have created a test entity i called generic_entity and i would like to have its "display page" , a node that display the entity properties in its content , to be editable in the same way the *My Account* is.

---

implementation of the hook_menu()

```
function test_entity_menu(){
//other menu links...
$items['test_entity/%test_entity'] = array(
    'title' => 'Display test_entity',
    'page callback' => 'test_entity_view_page',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access arguments' => array('display test_entity'),
);
}
```

end here is the test_entity_view_page()

```
function test_entity_view_page($test_entity, $view_mode = 'full'){ 
    $test_entity->content = array();    
    //to display fields attached to the entity through drupal 
    field_attach_prepare_view('test_entity', array($test_entity->ap_id => $test_entity), $view_mode);
    entity_prepare_view('test_entity', array($test_entity->ap_id => $test_entity));
    $test_entity->content += field_attach_view('test_entity', $test_entity, $view_mode);
    // to display a generic properties present in generic_entity.install
    $test_entity->content['test_entity_generic_property'] = array(
        '#type' => 'item',
        '#title' => t('Generic property'),
        '#markup' => $test_entity->test_entity_generic_property,
    );
    return $test_entity->content
}
```

In between of the two there are obviously the test_entity_load() and test_entity_load_multiple() methods.

Is there a way to have drupal generate *edit tabs* for this content the same way it does with the rest of the content created trhough the *Add content* feature?

Comment: What kind of custom content do you want to store? For example, site contact email, user specific data, meta info for other content and etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Module for creating "entity edit" form?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/52396/module-for-creating-entity-edit-form)

Comment: Sound to me since you want your entity to 'have its "display page" , a node that display the entity properties in its content'. You are probably better off having your module supply a node type, rather than an entity.

Comment: @2pha Im just trying to learn what i can about managing custom made entities, but in the case you suggested would my programmatically made custom node be "enveloped" inside the edit/add features?

Comment: @Letharion yes my question is very similar to yours, i somehow managed to fail to see it before posting mine.

Comment: Easily happens, no worries. I still do that mistake myself every now and then. :)